# What is difference between masterchef and smartchef contracts

Tags: pancakeswap, staking

I was going through masterchef contract. But later I saw Pancake uses smartchef contract for pools. I am confused which one to use, as both have almost same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

They have similar functionalities, there are key differences between the two contracts.

The `MasterChef` contract supports multiple pools, native token rewards, and allocation point management for flexible reward distribution, it also enables pool updates, additions, and removals, making it suitable for platforms with diverse staking options.

The `SmartChef` contract is designed for single pools, distributing non-native token rewards, ideal for focused or temporary campaigns, also it ffers simplicity and limited pool management, it is often used for promotional events or collaborations.